# SetWindowText with a single dimensional array

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to display a single dimensional array of values using SetWindowsText() in a text box on windows api?

for example. SetWindowText(hwndStatic3, sArray);

*******************************EDIT*************************

I have a textbox on the windows api where I use GetWindowText() to retrieve the string written in the text box then I convert the string to decimal array. I then convert this decimal array value to hexadecimal value as I am trying to print those values using SetwindowsText within another textbox. However only the last value of the array is printing. How can I print all the values?

*******************************EDIT*************************

code:

```
                    GetWindowText(hwndtext1, value, 256);

                    for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
                   {
                          temp[i] = atoll(value);       //converts sting to decimal
                          ulltoa(temp[i] , sArray, 16); //converts decimal to hexadecimal
                          buf[i] = temp[i];  

                    }
                          SetWindowText(hwndStatic3, sArray);
```

Comment: No, it will only display a string. You must convert the array to a string first.

Comment: I don't suppose you can provide the code that (a) performs the multiple steps of conversion you've mentioned, and (b) the code that attempts to set said results as window text using `SetWindowText()`? Also, you're doing this under Windows, so have you bothered to **debug** this?

Comment: What is the loop for?

Answer (score 1):

`SetWindowText` is just a macro with signature:

```
BOOL SetWindowText(HWND, const TCHAR*);
```

Depending on your build settings, it will call one of the following:

```
BOOL SetWindowTextA(HWND, const char*);    //ansi version
BOOL SetWindowTextW(HWND, const wchar_t*); //unicode version
```

where `TCHAR` is defined as:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

So, **an array of strings is not compatible with `SetWindowText`** but an array of characters will work, provided that the array is of type `TCHAR *`, or of type (`char *` or `wchar_t *`) that is compatible with your settings.

Answer (score 0):

First, `atoll` and `ulltoa` aren't documented with the Microsoft Visual C/C++ (which is what I use for Windows) so I'm working from documentation I found online.  Either your versions do more than those I've found documented, or you've left out some significant code from your example.

Based on the loop control, I'm guessing that you expect to always find 15 values in the string you *read* from the first control.  BUT...  the `atoll` and `ulltoa` functions only operate on **one** value at a time and do nothing to advance through the input list.  So your loop is converting the *first* number from string to 64 bit int and then converting that into a string 15 times.

Since you say the *last* value is the only one you see, your functions must actually be parsing the `value` string in some way that is not apparent in your example.  However, `ulltoa` seems to always be placing the value into the same place in the same string variable, with each subsequent call in the loop overwriting the previous call.  My lazy self would add a bit like this:

```
int len = 0;
char szOutput[15*20];     // enough space for 15 64 bit hex strings

GetWindowText(hwndtext1, value, 256);

for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
{
    temp[i] = atoll(value);       //converts sting to decimal
    ulltoa(temp[i] , sArray, 16); //converts decimal to hexadecimal
    buf[i] = temp[i];
    len += sprintf( szOutput+len, "%s ", sArray );
}
szOutput[len-1] - '\0'; // remove the final space
SetWindowText(hwndStatic3, szOutput);
```

Of course, with the `sprintf` you could also skip the `ulltoa` call entirely and change the `sprintf` line to:

```
    len += sprintf( szOutput+len, "%16.16I64X", temp[i] );
```

(or whatever flavor/form of the hex output you want (see the `printf` format documentation for details.)  If you want your list to be one item per line, then replace the trailing space with a newline.  Oh, the `I64` in the `%16.16I64X` is a Microsoft thing that might be different in other compilers/libraries.

FYI, the `sprintf` technique I used lets the function keep appending to the end of the buffer but incrementing the offset into the buffer (`len`) by the length of the string just appended, which is the value returned by `sprintf`.  It is a quick and easy way to assembling string lists such as yours.